# On screen keyboard with a different language on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard, on-screen-keyboard

I have a norwegian keyboard, but I want to be able to type in farsi/persian with on screen keyboard without changing the system locale.

Does anybody know of any software that does this?

I have tried [xvkbd](http://homepage3.nifty.com/tsato/xvkbd/) but it only shows in english.

Even if I change system keyboard layout to be farsi/persian it still doesn't work. Still it shows in Norwegian or english :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [Gnome On-Screen Keyboard](http://live.gnome.org/Gok) (gok), it has the ability to specify custom keyboard layouts via an XML file. Unfortunately the XML format is not documented well, and a GUI editor does not exist yet. I can't find any other on-screen keyboards that offer this though.

install it with `sudo apt-get install gok`

**Update**: Re the default Ubuntu on-screen keyboard 'onboard', see if [this thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=666853) is of any help. The last post says that persian and arabic are pretty close, perhaps that translation could be the base for your custom layout. place the file in `/home/user/.sok/layouts` and choose it in `onboard-settings`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Seemed like onboard worked with arabic language. Should be possible for me to modify it since there are so much similarities between the languages.

Answer (score 0):

This is a two step process.  First add Persian to the list of languages that you want to use and then turn on on-screen keyboard.
To type Persian you need to add the Persian language to the list of languages that you want to be able to use on Ubuntu.  Then you can switch between them.  To add a language go to your Ubuntu settings, and search for language, you will see the "Region & Language" section.  Within the section you will see the "Input Sources".  Under the "Input Sources" is all your installed languages along with a plus sign.  Click on the Plus sign and choose Persian to add it to your list of languages that you want to use.
To see the keyboard on screen open the Ubuntu settings and search for the word "access".  You will see the section "Universal Access".  Click on it and the page will open.  Under the section "Typing" select on-screen keyboard.  Now every-time you need to type the on-screen keyboard will appear in any language that you are using.  You can easily change between your list of languages be clicking on the top right hand corner of your screen where it shows the currently chosen language.  When you change the language that you are4 using the on-screen keyboard changes to that language's keyboard also.

I hope this helps.